# Transformation cannot be added to style in Angular directive in IE only

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, internet-explorer

I have created an angular directive that creates a photo gallery.  Sometimes the images have to be rotated, which I am doing through the CSS transform property (appended to the style in the directive):

```
testApp.directive('galPhoto', function () {
        return {            
            restrict: 'E',
            template:
                '<div class="photoClass" style="background-image:url({{photo.url}});{{photo.photoTransform}}" ng-click="addRotation($event, photo)"></div>'
        }
});
```

This all works fine in Firefox and Webkit browsers, however in Internet Explorer (I am testing on IE11) the transform property does not appear to get added to the style (only the background appears in the style).  I have tried setting with ng-style as well without any luck.  It is not a problem with the CSS transform as if I manually change the style everything works.  I have created a very simplified [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dj7xK/3/) which shows the problem, working in Firefox and Chrome but not in Internet Explorer.  In the Fiddle I added a ng-click which manually appends the transform to the style to show that setting the style works, it is just that Angular appears to be doing something when building the style string in Internet Explorer.  Any ideas how to fix?

[Fiddle Demonstrating Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/Dj7xK/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't know where the problem come from, but anyway, you're not doing this the AngularJS way. Why don't you use the [`ngStyle`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) directive? You will avoid this dirty code repetition in your data, and this works perfectly in all browsers.

```js
// The data associated to each image
{
    url: 'http://placekitten.com/100/150',
    transform: 'rotate(' + rotate + 'deg)',
}
```

```html
<!-- The template -->
<div
    class="photoClass"
    ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(' + photo.url + ')', '-webkit-transform': photo.transform, '-ms-transform': photo.transform, transform: photo.transform}"
    ng-click="addRotation($event, photo)"
></div>
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dj7xK/5/)</kbd>

Comment: It was done that way because the transform was used elsewhere as a string, but I have re-factored and switched to using ng-style, I was having issues with backslashed quotes but at least it works now.  Thanks.